# Mongoose method findOne takes too long and returns sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im calling findOne to find a user and then Im saving his commands into my variable commands, which I return and it is sometimes undefined.

```
const findAllCommands = async (user) => {
const commands = [];
const cache = await checkCache(user);
if (cache) {
  logger.info('Existing CACHE found!');
  return cache;
}
await User.findOne({ username: user }, (err, res) => {
if (err) {
  logger.error('ERROR: ' + err);
  throw new Error(err);
}
res.commands.forEach((v) => {
  commands.push(v);})
});

await addToCache(user, JSON.stringify(commands));
return commands;
};
```

Comment: You dont need the foreach at all. Just select only the commands.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works without a foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a `try catch` block whenever I use `async await` syntax. Also  if you need only one field you can query only for that field.

```
const findAllCommands = async (user) => {
  try {
    const cache = await checkCache(user);
    if (cache) {
      logger.info('Existing CACHE found!');
      return cache;
    }
    const commands = await User.findOne({ username: user }, "commands");
    await addToCache(user, JSON.stringify(commands));
    return commands;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

Comment: If it's still taking long to make the query, check to see how long it takes you to query & save to the cache as well.

Comment: Oh I see know, I literally dont know, why I wrote a foreach there. Thank you!